# Debugging nodes src/http.js with node-inspector

Tags: node.js, debugging

I'm having some bad luck debugging a node.js application. The problem is that I need to set a breakpoint in a file that isn't loaded at start (when --debug-blk) hits in. The file is http.js from node itself.

So I would like to modify the file to add a debugger; statement, but I'm unable to find this http.js file on my disk? The only place I see it on my disk is in the source distribution of node (lib/http.js). Where is this file located after a make install in node-src, and how can I set breakpoints inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http.js is internal to the node executable.  It doesn't exist on disk, and the only way to modify it is to build node from source.

Do this:

```
var http = require('http');
debugger;

// the rest of your app
```

Your app will start, load http, and then pause.  Now you can use the inspector to set breakpoints inside http.  (You won't need `--debug-brk` since the `debugger` statement will pause the app before anything really happens.)

Comment: Good answer! Was the part with --debug-brk meant for regular node debug srv.js or for node --debug srv.js? I use node-inspector for debugging. It has trouble with debugger; unless you use --debug-brk I found out.

Comment: There are two ways to start node and instruct it to listen for debugger connections: `node --debug app.js` and `node --debug-brk app.js`.  Both do the same thing; the only difference is that `--debug-brk` inserts a breakpoint on line 1 of app.js.