# node-inspector not working on linux server

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu-12.04, node-inspector

I have a linux (Ubuntu 12.04) server running nodejs and node-inspector for debug, however I cannot access the debug from another machine, running windows.

Here is what I got:

- Downloaded the most recent stable version (v0.10.18) from nodejs site for linux.
- Then I cd to `$HOME/Downloads/node-v0.10.18-linux-x86/bin`
- Installed node-inspector with `./npm install -g node-inspector`
- Start node-inspector with `./node node-inspector`
- Then I open another tab or terminal window and run my program with debug mode on the same directory: `./node --debug http.js`

On another machine (windows), in the same network, I open google chrome and type at the address bar:
`http://192.168.13.175:8080/debug?port=5858`

And I get blank screen such as this:
[image]

Clicked on the sources at the top left corner, but nothing. I know it is connected, because if I kill node.js with Ctrl+C I immediately get a message ***Detached from the target*** from chrome.

Any ideas what is going on? Firewall on windows is already down and both machines can see each other with ping test. One is `192.168.13.175` and the other is `192.168.13.56`.

Answer (score 0):

[Debugging nodes src/http.js with node-inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338857/debugging-nodes-src-http-js-with-node-inspector) You can try putting a breakpoint and used it like ./node --debug-brk http.js

Comment: Already tried that, but it didn't worked. The result is the same when I use chrome on ubuntu. I'm running it on a Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have adblock disabled as well as any other content blocking scripts and plugins.

See [issue #220](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/220) for the related discussion.

If this does not help then open a new issue on GitHub please, it's a better place for troubleshooting possible bugs.